# assigning files of a group to another one

Tags: linux, group

I want to delete a group using `groupdel` command, but before doing this I want to assign all files belonging to this group to another one is there a way to do this?

I know that I can use `find / -gid group_id` to find files that belong to this groups and then manually assign them to new one. I seek a way to automatically do the task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`find / -group <groupname> -exec chown :<groupname> {} \+`

should do the trick. Just replace `<groupname>` with the appropriate name.

`find` allows you to call arbitrary commands on the files it returns, using the `-exec` primary. In this case, as we know we want to change the group ownership of each matching file, we can simply pass the `chown` command (and any arguments - in this case, the group name to whose ownership we wish to transfer matching file names, preceded by `:`, which tells `chown` to treat it as a group name and not as a user name) as the argument to `-exec`. The file name returned by `find` is inserted into the command in place of the `{}`, and `+;` tells `find` that it has reached the end of the external command, and should parse any additional parameters as its own.   Using `\+` rather than `\;` tells find to process multiple files in each command (so it's more efficient).

Comment: Please explain it a bit more.

Comment: Edited my answer. Does that clear it up a bit?